# Degree of a map from sphere to general linear group is mutliple of (n-1)!

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, general-linear-group

I am trying to understand Atiyah's paper "[Algebraic Topology and Elliptic Operators](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cpa.3160200202)" (link is pay-walled). In the paper he defines the degree of a map from $S^{2n-1}\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ by mapping to the first column and then normalizing to obtain a map $S^{2n-1}\rightarrow S^{2n-1}$ which has the usual notion of degree.

He claims that the degree of such a map will be a multiple of $(n-1)!$. Can anyone explain why this should be true? I am also interested in a reference with this notion of degree.

Comment: Presumably the factorial is coming from the fact that the map $GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow S^{2n-1}$ factors through maps from k-frames in $\mathbb{C}^n$ to (k-1)-frames in $\mathbb{C}^n$. So one should analyze the fibrations $F \rightarrow V_k (\mathbb{C}^n) \rightarrow V_{k-1}(\mathbb{C}^n)$.

Comment: I should add that glancing at the homotopy groups of $Gl(n,\mathbb{C})$ you see that $\pi_{2n}$ appears to be $\mathbb{Z}_{n!}$. Perhaps for the fiber $F'$ of the map $GL(n) \rightarrow S^{2n-1}$  something like $F' \simeq \Omega ^2 U(n)$ is known?